# Configuring Pub/Sub for Restful API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to configure a pub/sub subscription to receive messages from a public Restful API. I am unable to locate any such thing in the tutorials or the google docs. Is there any tutorial with the steps needed anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do if you understand Google Cloud, Authentication and the documentation.

This Cloud Pub/Sub API documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/). If you are just getting started with Google Cloud, this documentation assumes that you already know the basics.

The service account authentication is [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).

I would start by first getting comfortable with Pub/Sub in your favorite language using a library. Start [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/apis).